# Selecionar Indicador, Indicados e Indicados de Indicados

Tags: mysql

Salve, galera.
Estou com uma tabela no MySQL em que cada registro tem o CPF do associado e o CPF do indicador (quem o indicou).

Estou tentando selecionar tanto o indicado quanto seus indicadores.
Por exemplo: Eu indiquei A, A indicou B e B indicou C.
Quero que a partir de A eu consiga mapear todos os indicados seguintes.

Até então tenho a seguinte consulta, que só trás o indicado direto:

```
SELECT u.*, s.statusdesc AS ststatus, p.plandesc, p.planval,
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE uscpfindicador = u.uscpf) AS indicados
            FROM usuarios u, planos p, usstatus s
            LEFT JOIN usuarios AS child
                ON child.usid = usid
            WHERE u.usstatus = s.statusid
                AND u.usplano = p.planid
                AND u.uscpfindicador = 0123456
            GROUP BY u.usid;
```

A tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `usid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usnome` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `usnascimento` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `uscpf` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ustelefone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uscelular` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uscpfindicador` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `usvencimento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usendereco` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `usbanco` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `usagencia` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `usconta` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `usoperacao` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `usfavorecido` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `usemail` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ussenha` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `usvendedor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'boolean',
  `usstatus` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `usplano` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `usdepende` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'se o usuário for dependente de alguém, o id do usuário do qual ele depende',
  `ustipocad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usparentesco` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `usadmin` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `recover` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`usid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uscpf` (`uscpf`),
  KEY `usplano` (`usplano`),
  KEY `usstatus` (`usstatus`),
  KEY `FkTipoCad` (`ustipocad`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Inserção de dados teste:

```
INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`usid`, `usnome`, `usnascimento`, `uscpf`, `ustelefone`, `uscelular`, `uscpfindicador`, `usvencimento`, `usendereco`, `usbanco`, `usagencia`, `usconta`, `usoperacao`, `usfavorecido`, `usemail`, `ussenha`, `usvendedor`, `usstatus`, `usplano`, `usdepende`, `ustipocad`, `usparentesco`, `usadmin`, `recover`) VALUES
(1, 'EMPRESA', '1988-05-29', '0123456', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'email@email.com', '7bca1fa5a8bcc4df3933e77c644b8cd1', 1, 1, 1, NULL, 3, NULL, 1, 0),
(2, 'Indicado pela empresa', '1992-03-22', '12345678910', '210000000', '21900000000', '0123456', 10, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Jhonatan Pereira', 'jhonatan_pereira@msn.com', '709aae0fea527912f8a02cf1d7c20819', 1, 1, 1, NULL, 3, NULL, 0, 0),
(6, 'Indicado pelo indicado', '1992-03-22', '12312312311', '210000000', '21900000000', '12345678910', 10, 'Av Teste', '', '', '', '', '', 'email@email.com', '709aae0fea527912f8a02cf1d7c20819', 1, 1, 1, NULL, 3, NULL, 0, 0);
```

Um exemplo de resultado da consulta seria retornar esses três dados, já que um indicou o outro, a partir do primeiro registro. Nesse caso, eu preciso somente desses 2 níveis de profundidade, o principal, quem ele indicou e o indicado pelo indicado.

Aprecio qualquer ajuda e se precisar de mais informações só comentar.

**EDITADO**
SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bae60/3

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver!
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bae60/6

Serve para Marketing Multinivel, se alguém desejar.